# Initialize NSMutableArray in class type UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, uicollectionviewcell

i downladed a demo that includes the next class CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell.h with the following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *displayString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *windows;

@end
```

and the CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell.m with the following:

```
#import "CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell.h"

@interface CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell ()
@end

@implementation CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell
@synthesize windows;

int i=0;


- (void)setDisplayString:(NSString *)displayString {
    windows=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (![_displayString isEqualToString:displayString]) {
        _displayString = [displayString copy];
        //self.displayLabel.text = _displayString;

        int n=[_displayString intValue];
        n=n+1;
        self.displayLabel.tag=n;
        NSString* image = [@(n) description];
        UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:[image stringByAppendingString:@".png"]];
        CGSize imgSize = self.displayLabel.frame.size;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        self.displayLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
        self.displayLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
        [self.displayLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
}

-(void)labelTap{

    NSLog(@"tapped %d",self.displayLabel.tag);
    int n=self.displayLabel.tag;
    NSString *idWindow=[@(n) description];
    [windows addObject:idWindow];
}
```

this is call from a ViewController and display a view like pinterest, but it was only the view, so I added these lines:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
            [self.displayLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

to catch when a label is clicked. And the method `-(void)labelTap`, to print what label of the view is clicked, I'm having problems, because i want to add the tags of the label clicked, in a nsmutablearray, but if i do the alloc in the method `-(void)labelTap`, every time a label is clicked the array is deleted, I, tried to put it in the `(void)setDisplayString:(NSString *)displayString` but for a strange reason creates a array for each tag of the label, that means that store the 1's clicked in an array the 2's in other array etc...

Well I hope you can help me, this is the full demo that I'm using:

[demo](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you have written below line inside `- (void)setDisplayString:(NSString *)displayString` this method. So each time when it is being called you mutable array is initialized. Write the below line in some different method.

```
 windows=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I tried to call it in the -(void)labelTap, but it's the same, the NSMutableArray is deleted every time i click a label, Is there a method to initialize?? like ViewDidLoad

Comment: No don't call in this method. This will execute each time right. Inspite of this mention in the your init method or something